# Поиск файлов в директории

Tags: c++

Как в линукс на C++ получить список всех файлов в директории (включая вложенные директории)?

Comment: Был уже очень похожий вопрос. Мой ответ http://hashcode.ru/questions/10856/список-файлов-в-директории-и-ее-поддиректориях?страница=1#10861

Answer (score 5, accepted):

+1 к `opendir()`/`readdir()`/`stat()`/`closedir()`. А вот парсить вывод `ls`  я бы не стал: во-первых, это долго, а, во-вторых, вывод ls может сильно отличаться в различных системах и локальных настройках.

Есть ещё BSD-шный `fts()`, как вариант.

Answer (score 3):

Можно еще использовать `fs::recursive_directory_iterator` из библиотеки boost.

Answer (score 2):

Первый способ - рекурсивно по директориям opendir(), readdir(), stat() для определения типа.

Второй - чтение и анализ вывода popen("ls -lR","r");

Comment: Второй - нэ надо.